# Writing the equations indented with respect to equal sign

Tags: equations, indentation

I want to write the equations indented with respect to equation signs. I have tried number of examples available but I couldn't get it done. I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Kile as the editor and compiler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Let's see

 \begin{equation}
\begin{split}


     (k+1)^3 - (k+1) ={}& k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 - k -1\\
                 ={}& (k^3 - k) + 3(k^2 + k)\\
                ={}& 3m + 3 (K^2 + k)\\
                 ={}& 3 (m + k^2 + k) \\
                 ={}& 3 M     

 \end{split}

 \end{equation}







\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should have no blank line inside `equation`; then the correct syntax would be `&=`, not `={}&`

Comment: Please [accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer, if an answer worked for you personally. Also to close the open question. If you need further help you can comment an answer or ask a new question. Have fun with latex.

Answer (score 5):

`&` *precedes* the alignment point. In `split` you should generally use `&=`, `={}&` *might* be used in special occasions, but very rare.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Let's see
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(k+1)^3 - (k+1) &= k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 - k -1\\
                &= (k^3 - k) + 3(k^2 + k)\\
                &= 3m + 3 (K^2 + k)\\
                &= 3 (m + k^2 + k) \\
                &= 3 M
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Never have blank lines between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, nor before `\begin{equation}`.

[image]

The result you get is probably

[image]

but this is accompanied by several error messages by the compiler, which you shouldn't disregard.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical example of the use of `align` and friends:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (k+1)^3 - (k+1) &= k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 - k -1 \\
                  &= (k^3 - k) + 3(k^2 + k) \\
                  &= 3m + 3 (K^2 + k) \\
                  &= 3 (m + k^2 + k) \\
                  &= 3 M     
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Content is centred and aligned using `&`. Care is taken to preserve spacing around the relation when using `&=`.

Comment: Since `split` is the correct environment for this case, it's quite hard to understand why you're promoting `align*`.

Comment: @egreg: Don't dwell on it. Only now do I see the use of `equation` for a number.

Comment: @egreg I'm just curious, why is `split`  preferred over `align` ? 
If you use the normal `align` it will also produce equation numbers

Comment: @ChristophS With split you get just one without any manual intervention.

Comment: @ChristophS: Yes, one for each line. In this case, the OP might only be interested in a single numbering for the entire equation set. One may still use `align` and `\nonumber` those that shouldn't be numbered, but this is better achieved using `split`.